# Test attribute of the json response returned by open policy agent with opa test

Tags: open-policy-agent

Is there a way to test value of a key/attribute inside the json response of the decision returned by OPA.(Response returned is not yes/no but a json with key allow which dictates the decision)
For example:

```
test_get_user_allowed_for_admin {
        decision["allow"] with input as {"path": ["users", "kate"], "method": "GET", "user_id": "bob"}
}
```

Let’s say the policy evaluated is of the form:

```
get_user_info = decision{
    decision := {
      "allow": input.user_id == "bob", "user_id": input.user_id,
  }
}
```

currently I get a `var decision is unsafe` error because decision is not defined in the `test_get_user_allowed_for_admin` but that is just a filler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test can check the value generated by the rule `get_user_info` just like any other value (e.g., `input`, a local variable, etc.)

For example:

```
test_get_user_allowed_for_admin {
  in := {
    "path": ["users", "kate"],
    "method": "GET",
    "user_id": "bob"
  }

  result := get_user_info with input as in
  result.allow == true
  result.user_id == "bob"
}

# OR

test_get_user_allowed_for_admin_alt {
  in := {
    "path": ["users", "kate"],
    "method": "GET",
    "user_id": "bob"
  }
  result := get_user_info with input as in
  result == {"allow": true, "user_id": "bob"}
}
```

Technically you don't have to assign the value generated by `get_user_info` a variable:

```
test_get_user_allowed_for_admin_oneline {
  in := {
    "path": ["users", "kate"],
    "method": "GET",
    "user_id": "bob"
  }
  get_user_info.allow with input as in
}
```